# Unable to add reference to Word 2013 Interop Assembly

Tags: office-2013, office-pia

I have an existing .Net application that does some Word Interop work. On one machine where I have Word 2010 installed, I am able to reference the Word PIA (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) with no problem, compile, run - everything is great.  Now, I'm trying to test against Word 2013 to ensure that my application is compatible with it.  So on another machine with only Office 2013 installed (no other instances of Office), I try to build the same exact source code, but get compilation errors because VS2010 can't find the Word PIA. I tried updating the reference of the PIA, but it does not show up in the list of available assemblies.

I checked my installation of Office - every component available is installed, including .Net Programmability Support for Word. I looked at the GAC in Windows Explorer, and the assembly appears to be there. I tried restarting multiple times.

My application targets the .Net Framework 3.5 (but I also tried changing that to 4.0). I'm working in VS2010 Professional, and I have Office Professional Plus 2013 installed on the box.  What could I be missing??

Thanks.